# google cloud endpoint callback after update

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is it possible to use a cloud endpoint method as the callback for an upload?
The uploadUrl is generated using the blobservice.

```
String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/_ah/api/project/v1/uploadcallback" , options);
```

For the moment, I get a 404 response from app engine server.

I get the following exception from the local test server :

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /_ah/upload/agtrdWJpdHktdGVzdHIbCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGAEM. Reason:

    Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3d3f1775; line: 1, column: 3]

Caused by:

com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)) in numeric value: expected digit (0-9) to follow minus sign, for valid numeric value
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@3d3f1775; line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserBase.reportUnexpectedNumberChar(JsonParserBase.java:960)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._handleInvalidNumberStart(ReaderBasedParser.java:957)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.parseNumberText(ReaderBasedParser.java:671)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:476)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2761)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2709)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1854)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet$LilyRequestMarshaller.createBackendRequestBody(RestApiServlet.java:76)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet$LilyRequestMarshaller.marshall(RestApiServlet.java:59)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet$LilyRequestMarshaller.access$100(RestApiServlet.java:54)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:144)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.handleUpload(UploadBlobServlet.java:432)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.access$000(UploadBlobServlet.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet$1.run(UploadBlobServlet.java:117)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.UploadBlobServlet.doPost(UploadBlobServlet.java:114)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Uploading a Blob](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob):

> The form must include a file upload field, and the form's enctype must
>   be set to `multipart/form-data`. When the user submits the form, the
>   POST is handled by the Blobstore API, which creates the blob. The API
>   also creates an info record for the blob and stores the record in the
>   datastore, and passes the rewritten request to your application on the
>   given path as a blob key.

As Endpoints doesn't (as far as I know) accept `multipart/form-data` as a valid encoding, this won't work. The error messaging you see is because the Endpoint is expecting JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will monitor the request response to check how it's build.

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem. It appears it's an issue with Endpoints and the fact that JSON is being POSTed.

In the end I just stepped outside the Endpoints framework and had a custom servlet handle the POST.

Everything else so far is still inside the Endpoints.