# Google Cloud Endpoints Exception on API URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm getting an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when trying to access `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api`:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>
> > at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
> >         at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.DevApiUtil.stripLeadingSlash(DevApiUtil.java:17)
> >         at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet.service(RestApiServlet.java:120)
> >         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
> >         at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:123)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
> >         at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
> >         at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
> >         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
> >         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
> >         at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
> >         at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

I'm trying to use Endpoints, so I created an `Entity` as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String password;

    private String username;

    public User() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

}

Then, I right clicked on the class Google appEngine WTP --> generate Cloud Endpoint Class....

I'm following the getting started tutorial  https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-js

My Index.html is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Hello App Engine</title>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello App Engine!</h1>
      <script>
        function init(){
         var ROOT = 'http://localhost:8080/_ah/api';
            gapi.client.load('libuserendpoint', 'v1', function() {
              alert("hello");
            }, ROOT);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you figured this issue out?

Answer (score 1):

The correct URL for Google APIs Explorer in your local environment is localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you may need a slash to start the URL, so maybe the URL needs to look like:

```
_ah/api
```

Instead of:

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/api
```

I saw the following question which made me think of this:

[google cloud enpoint callback after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434428/google-cloud-enpoint-callback-after-update)