# What to pass to `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl` so it is handled by my endpoint method

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, blobstore

My question is similar to [getting blobstore to callback to endpoint method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155920/getting-blobstore-to-callback-to-endpoint-method) but s/he got no reply. Also I actually wrote my code. I created my callback url as

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String url = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/loadImages");
```

And then I created my endpoint as

```
@ApiMethod(name = "loadImages", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void loadImages(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest req) {
  //…. get blob key etc.
}
```

Then I get an error on my server when the blobstore makes the callback call:

```
No handlers matched this URL. (404)
```

Does anyone know what to pass to `blobstoreService.createUploadUrl` so it is handled by my endpoint method?

I have also tried changing `”/loadImages”` to `"/_ah/spi/com.company.package.ApiName.loadImages”` so that it looks like the other paths, but that didn’t work either. Then I tried `"_ah/api/apiname/1/loadImages”`: nothing.

Note: I am not looking for an alternative to the blobstore/endpoint. When I use simple servlet to receive the callback it works. But the servlet just cheapens my otherwise endpoint-only code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can only user servlets to handle this type of callback. I've been looking for solution for several hours and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434428/google-cloud-enpoint-callback-after-update).

In short:

> The form must include a file upload field, and the form's enctype must
>   be set to **multipart/form-data**. The API  ... **passes the rewritten request** to your application on the
>   given path as a blob key.
>
> As Endpoints doesn't (as far as I know) accept **multipart/form-data** as
>   a valid encoding, this won't work. The error messaging you see is
>   because the Endpoint is expecting JSON.